# Is there a simple way to set multiple dimention value of numpy array with multiple array of index

Tags: python, numpy

#### background:

the states of atmosphere are stored in a 3d array `c`.

`latitude`, `longitude` is the horizontal coordinates of the states, `level` is the atmosphere vertical levels.

`x` -> longitude index, `y` -> latitude index

A 2d level array `z` is to store the stratosphere levels.

For each position `(x,y)`, the states in `c` above the stratosphere level `z(x,y)` should be set to 0.

#### question:

We can use the loop implementation, but it colud be very slow when the atmopshere array `c` is veray large.

```py
import numpy as np
x = range(10)
y = range(10)
z = np.ones((10,10)) * 3
c = np.ones((10,10,10))
xmap, ymap = np.meshgrid(x,y)

# loop implementation
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
         c[int(z[i,j]):, i, j ] = 0

# is there any simple code to do that
# I suppose the code like:

# c[z:, xmap, ymap] = 0

# but it doesn't work.
```

Comment: An array can't be used to specify a slice, tbat is the `z:` part

Comment: What is your expected output? Also, your loop implementation also fails. What do you want to achieve? `z` is a `10x10` matrix. Why do you want to use it as an index for the first dimension of `c`? What does that even mean?

Comment: Is `z` always the same value, `3`?

Comment: change to `z = np.ones((10,10)).astype(int) * 3` ?

Comment: `c[3:, :, :] = 0` should be enough if all value of `z` are `3`.

Comment: `np.ones` makes a float dtype array by default.  That can't be use as index - directly or element-wise.  Indexing requires an integer array, and slicing requires scalar integers.

Comment: I'd suggest posting a new question with a (10,10) `c`, and `(10,)` `z`.  I don't think the 3d/2d combo is essential.  Or even use something smaller like (3,3).  And give `z` is real diversity, not just '3's.  Your desired results for this 3d case are hard to visualize.

Comment: Sorry for the code mistake. I simplified the original code, and did not test it. I add some description of the backgound. Hope make the quetion more clear.